# C# read from file - integer and ignore everything else

Tags: c#

I have a config.txt file which looks something like this

```
some text here = 5
another text line here = 4 with random garbage
some other line = 2 5 some number 12
7
foo bar 9
```

To clarify, ONLY the number right after " = ". Just that one number that shows up after "="

I want to be able to extract the integers ONLY after " = ". So in this case, the output should look like

```
5
4
2
```

I've done this before in C++ with something like this

```
if (file_to_read.is_open()) {
        file_to_read.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '='); 
        while (file_to_read >> input) { 
            values.push_back(input);
            file_to_read.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '=');
        }
        file_to_read.close();
```

I want to understand how you do this in C# and if there's any documentation I can refer to

Comment: Shouldn't the output be 5 and 4?

Comment: Just use a `= (\d+)` regex...

Comment: @Albert Alonso , yes it should be 5 and 4. Apologies for the typo.

Comment: That is correct @RufusL it was a

Comment: done. Thanks again @RufusL

Comment: And what if there is more than one number on a line, should it pick its favourite? please be specific with these things

Comment: There's lots of info out there on how to read a text file with c#, how to do a `foreach`, `for`, or `while` loop (to process the file data), and how to compare characters to different values. What have you tried so far? If you show us where you're stuck, it would be easier to help.

Comment: @MichaelRandall updated the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regular expressions, the procedure isn't too complicated. Filtering while reading a stream seems far too complex for this. Simply do this:

- Read the text file into a single string
- Use a regex that searches for a pattern containing the literal `" = "` string, followed by numeric characters `\d+`.
- Putting the numeric part of the expression in round brackets allows you to capture it as group #1, which you can extract from the `Match` object as `m.Groups[1].Value`.
- Each found integer is parsed and added to a list of integers
- After the operation, the list is returned.

  ```
  public static List<Int32> ExtractInts(String filePath)
  {
      String input = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
      List<Int32> ints = new List<Int32>();
      Regex r = new Regex(" = (\\d+)");
      MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(input);
      foreach(Match m in mc)
          ints.Add(Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value));
      return ints;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
string input =
@"some text here = 5
another text line here = 4 with random garbage
some other line = 2 5 some number 12
7
foo bar 9";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?:.*(?<==).*)(\d+)");
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
5
4
2
```

For Regex here is what happens:
Non-selective lookbehind for any symbol any number of times followed by '=' sign:

```
(?:.*(?<==).*)
```

And this is for matching digits:

```
(\d+)
```

You are welcome. =)

Comment: If you use a capture group you don't need the lookbehind. You can just use literal " = " before the \d.